iptables to nftfilter
Here's part of my firewall script that's been broken by nft.
iptables-nft -n -L LOGTABLE 2>&1 >/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        # LOG table already exists, so clear it.
        iptables -t LOGTABLE -F
else
        # LOG table doesn't exist, so create it.
        iptables -N LOGTABLE
fi
iptables -A LOGTABLE -m limit --limit 1/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables-LOG" --log-level 4
iptables -A LOGTABLE -j REJECT

I'm trying to convert it but iptables-translate gives wrong answers. For example:
# iptables-translate -t LOGTABLE -F
nft flush table ip LOGTABLE
# nft flush table ip LOGTABLE
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
flush table ip LOGTABLE
               ^^^^^^^^
#

And iptables-nft is also broken
# iptables-nft -t LOGTABLE -F
iptables v1.8.9 (nf_tables): table 'LOGTABLE' does not exist
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

All seems very slipshod -- I guess you get what you pay for.
Possible solutions?
Wasn't expecting to have to learn a new tool to completely rewrite and test my firewall script.

iptables-save > /tmp/iptables iptables-restore-translate -f /tmp/iptables
